# module not found in react js when using a path of image

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

i just started react js but having trouble in importing a path of image to the webpage. I have a folder named assets and it have images, i want to use those images in my project but when giving it as a input in the code it shows: "ERROR in ./src/containers/products/Products.jsx 7:0-33
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../assets/'"

Here is the code for the following

```
import React from 'react';
import './products.css';
import {Prodfeat} from '../../components'
import logo from '../../assets/';

const Products = () => {
    return (
      <div className='gpt3__products' id='products'>
        <div className='gpt3__products-heading'>
          <h1>We have something for everyone!</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Prodfeat title='product 1' text='description of product1' productimg={`${logo}blog01.png`}/>
          <Prodfeat title='product 2' text='description of product2' productimg={`${logo}blog02.png`}/>
          <Prodfeat title='product 3' text='description of product3' productimg={`${logo}blog03.png`}/>
        </div>

      </div>
    )
  }
```

here is the code for the prodfeat component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './prodfeat.css';

const Prodfeat = ({title, text, productimg}) => {
  return (
    <div className='gpt3__prodfeat' >
        <div className='gpt3__prodfeat-desc'>
            <div className='gpt3__prodfeat-heading'>
                <h2>{title}</h2>
            </div>
            <div className='gpt3__prodfeat-text'>
                <p>{text}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src={productimg} alt={title}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

i want to use the {logo} as a reference variable and point toward the photo so that i dont have to write the path again and again but it is not accepting it as the path but just a string. Please if you got any suggestions guide me in this problem.
Thank you

Comment: `const logoPath = '../../assets';` - assign the path to a variable rather than an import.

Comment: are your images in the src file ?

Comment: are your images in the src file ?

Comment: yes they are in src file @monim

Comment: i also tried to assign the path to a variable but it was taken as a string @Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using  an absolute path when setting the `src` prop on the `img` element. you cannot achieve this when your images are located in the `src` folder . your images should be  located in the public directory . then you don't need to import them  just use the absolute path .

**In your case  :**
instead of  : `import logo from '../../assets/';`

put your images inside public folder and store the path to a variable like this  :

```
const logo = '<the path here >'
```

and access them :

```js
<Prodfeat title='product 1' text='description of product1' productimg={`${logo}blog01.png`}/>
```

I made a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/combobox-material-demo-forked-rbripk?file=/Products.js) to show you exactly how it works !

Comment: thank you so much now i am able to do the same

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in tailwind & next js !
I did everything but problems didnt go anywhere /:

So I send all string of my className and then problems gone !!

Answer (score 0):

use this import
`import logo from '../../assets/logo.<file_format>';`

Answer (score 0):

i think you missing the file to ref use

```
import logo from '../../assets/logo.xxx
```